# HTML Input file type using only Document option on Android/ios devices

Tags: html

I am using the following tag to upload an image from the user device to the server:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;” />
```

When I click on the input I am getting two options: Camera and Document.  Is there a way to show only the Document option?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 little problems here :

- first, your last quote i incorrect, change it to `"` (instead of `”`)
- second, you shouldn't have a `;` in your `accept`, remove it.

  ```
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" />
  ```